# Laravel using Policies and FormRequest classes together

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm using the [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation) classes to validate data being passed into my controllers.

Additionally, I'm using [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#policies) to determine if a current user is allowed to `show` / `update` / `destroy` etc the object in question.

If I am using Policies, does this mean I can simply use:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
```

within my Request classes? Or should I be doing the check twice / writing them in different ways?

If someone could shed some light on this, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can simply return true if you are using policies and no other check is required for the request.

Answer (score 0):

See \Illuminate\Validation\ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Validation;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\UnauthorizedException;

/**
 * Provides default implementation of ValidatesWhenResolved contract.
 */
trait ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait
{
    /**
     * Validate the class instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        $instance = $this->getValidatorInstance();

        if (! $this->passesAuthorization()) {
            $this->failedAuthorization();
        } elseif (! $instance->passes()) {
            $this->failedValidation($instance);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the validator instance for the request.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        return $this->validator();
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed validation attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw new ValidationException($validator);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the request passes the authorization check.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function passesAuthorization()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'authorize')) {
            return $this->authorize();
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function failedAuthorization()
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedException;
    }
}
```

And \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest

```
/**
 * Determine if the request passes the authorization check.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function passesAuthorization()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'authorize')) {
        return $this->container->call([$this, 'authorize']);
    }

    return false;
}
```

It only checks the returning result and determine to continue or not when the request is resolved. It doesn't pass the policies or any middleware or sth. strange like that.